# Testing Angular - How can I test disabled field using Selenium Protractor?

Tags: angular, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, protractor, disabled-input

In MEAN stack project I am using Selenium webdriver for frontend UI testing.

I have a field which is non editable. I have attached an image

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbtkD.png)

How can I test this field making sure it cannot be edited?

```
    it('not edit the field', () => {
        login('amazonuser');
        click(by.xpath('//mat-option[5]/span[contains(., "Amazon Id")]'));
        getElement(by.xpath('//id-number/div/mat-form-field[2]/div/div[1]/div/input')).sendKeys('0');
        logout();
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You assert that the `disabled` attribute is on the INPUT.

```
var input = element(by.xpath('//id-number/div/mat-form-field[2]/div/div[1]/div/input'))
expect(input.isEnabled()).toBe(true);
```

See [the HTML docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/disabled).
See [the Protractor docs](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.isEnabled).

Comment: I know but how should I code it using Selenium?

Comment: You should familiarize yourself with the Protractor docs. They have a lot of good examples. I've updated my answer with the code and a link to the docs.

Comment: can you help with this - stackoverflow.com/questions/75922947/angular-testing-how-to-check-if-error-icon-is-absent-is-valid-data-is-passed